# How can I connect two sockets on different machines?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm sure this seems like a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  I've been playing with basic client/server code in C, basically the same stuff that's posted on any intro socket programming guide, and no matter how I vary the few lines of code I can't connect two machines over the internet.  I can connect locally with 127.0.0.1 and all the examples work fine, but I want to be able to connect two separate hosts.

I've tried using IP addresses - ifconfig and curl ifconfig.me return different IP's for every machine or remote box I have access to and I've been told this means they're all behind NAT which means I can't connect with an explicit IP.

I've tried using username@hostname with gethostbyname() - I've been using whoami and hostname on the serving machine to determine the hostname the client should use, however the DNS always returns an error.  How should I determine the hostname I should supply to the client so that I can connect?

Other than that I'm not sure what the issue could be because I'm using the same socket code posted all over the web and I've checked every line many times against several different examples.  This has been frustrating me for a long time, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's likely the NAT that's the problem. You may have to NAT hole punch, but that requires you to have access to a machine outside of the NAT'ed networks.

Comment: What is the IP you are binding to? What is the IP that ifconfig says you have? Do you have admin access to your router? Are you using TCP or UDP?

Comment: Binding to INADDR_ANY, I do have access to the router but the ISP is AM3 in a multi-tennant building which may complicate things, and using TCP (SOCK_STREAM).

Comment: For testing network code, you might consider either using two machines that are connected to the same LAN or or getting shell access on a server that is connected directly to the Internet without a NAT or firewall in the way.